# Delay loading parts of a webpage with jQuery problem

Tags: jquery, load, delay

I have a webpage with a `div id="rate"`. I want to load the content of this div after the page is load with jQuery.
When queried, my server returns a VALID xhtml document (with a content type of "application/xhtml+xml") with what should be the contents of the rate div.

I have tried:

```
$('#rate').load('/wizard/false', function() {
    $("#rate").show("slow", function () {} );
});
```

As well as `$.get` - nothing seems to work. I keep getting `An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12` or hierarchy error (on all browsers).
When I place the content manually directly in the rate div, everything works fine.
You can check out the problematic page [here](http://www.funcampuses.com/rate/alabama-state-university).

Comment: You have invalid XML in there. This is what I get in firebug: `XML Parsing Error: junk after document element Location: moz-nullprincipal:{66945a3b-1a25-42b7-aabc-ab56dae19115} Line Number 1329, Column 1: <br/><br/><br/>`

Comment: thanks! this is xhtml, not xml. how do i let jquery know of that?

Comment: I wanted to help you. Was testing your site. But now it's down...

Answer (score 2):

Your xHTML that you are trying to load is not valid xHTML.

It starts with a doctype declaration, but has no 'html', 'body' or 'head' tags.

Try either removing the doctype, or putting in all those tags.

If you add those tags, you can then strip them by providing jQuery with the ID of the element that you want:

```
$('#rate').load('/wizard/false #rating-wizard', function(data) {
    // Do whatever you want
});
```

Look at the [jQuery Documentaion for .load](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Look for the heading "Loading Page Fragments".

Comment: thanks, but i dont want the content of my div to be <html>... how do i avoid that?

Comment: thanks joseph, but within the complete function of the get, how do i add the returned value to the #rate div? i updated my website and now the xhtml is valid. i am using `$('#rate').append(data);` and getting the error "Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy" code: "3"

Comment: What do you mean by "how do i add the returned value to the #rate div?"? If what you mean is that you want the `data` variable to contain only the `#rating-wizard` div, then you should do `data = $(data).find('#rating-wizard')`. BTW, remove those 3 `br` tags at the end.

Comment: i mean, how do i set the content of my container div (#rate) to the documents my $.get received? I am now only getting the rating-wizard div by using the code you provided above, but how do i put #rating-wizard inside #rate like so: <div id="rate><div id="rating-wizard>CONTENT</div></div>?

Comment: I updated the answer to use `load` instead of `get`. It's cleaner. However, if you want to use get, you should put this in your callback function: `$('#rate').html( $(data).find('#rating-wizard') )`.

Comment: thanks, but now i'm getting "An invalid or illegal string was specified" code: "12"... when i use load - however, `$('#rate').html( $(data).find('#rating-wizard') )` in the $.get worked!

Comment: actually, it doesn't :( i still get "An invalid or illegal string was specified" code: "12"